# Getting past computer password to settings without a keyboard. I just pulled my Mac out of storage, and the keyboard seems to not work

Tags: keyboard

The old keyboard input to the computer seems to not reflect the actual keys pressed.  I ordered a replacement keyboard from Amazon.  i am following the steps to pair it up, but the computer is not seeing it.  I do not know if this Mac meets the requirements of the keyboard.  Mac OS 10.7 or later and Bluetooth 4.0 or later.

Comment: You'd do better with a wired keyboard at this point. You also didn't tell us the keyboard, the Mac or vaguely what OS it might be on. Try [Ultimate Mac Lookup](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/) to at least identify the Mac.

Comment: You could always just plug in a $5 USB keyboard.  Keyboards are keyboards.

Comment: You could also use keyboard viewer which you can enable in keyboard settings by enabling "Show input menu in bar", then when you have enabled it, click on the Input Menu in your menu bar and select "Show Keyboard Viewer". Then you can click on the individual keys in Keyboard viewer using your mouse and it'll enter those keys in the password box :)